# Multimap of Multimap Java - Categorize timetable

Tags: java, object, arraylist, hashmap, multimap

I have parsed a HTML timetable and loaded every Subject to my class object.
So i have arrayList of my Subjects which has information of name, teacher,... ,HOUR, and DAY
now i want to reconstruct the table and so I need to categorize it first. I think that best would be to have structure like this:

```
Monday: 1: Math, Czech, ...
        2: History
        ...
Tuesday: 1: English, Geo
         2...
...
```

There can be mutiple subjects in given hour, therefore I tried to used Multimap of Multimap, but I am not able to declare it during my for parsing.

```
Multimap<String, Multimap<String, Subject>> timetable = HashMultimap.create();
...
for ...
    timetable.put(subject.den, new HashMultimap<>(subject.hod, subject));
```

but it says that HashMultimap has private accesin com.google.common...
I dont know how to correctly write this. I was also thinking about using Array, but I would have to pre-declare it and I would like to build this during one for cycle.
Any ideas? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like what you want is actually more of a `Map<String, Multimap<String, Subject>>`, in which case you want

```
 Map<String, Multimap<String, Subject>> timetable = new HashMap<>();
 for ...
   Multimap<String, Subject> multimap = timetable.get(subject.den);
   if (multimap == null) {
     multimap = HashMultimap.create();
     timetable.put(subject.den, multimap);
   }
   multimap.put(subject.hod, subject);
```

Comment: I love you man! This works exactly as I expected!
I have one more questin regarding this. How can I now extract propertie of the Object on certain Keys? Lets say I need name of Object which is 1st hour on monday. I would expect to find it like this `timetable.get("Monday").get("1")[1].name` but I am not sure how to exactly type that, because this doesnt work

Comment: What do you mean?  There can be several subjects in that place.  You can get them out by writing `Collection<Subject> subjects = timetable.get("Monday").get("1")`.

Comment: yea I meant if it is possible to extract only the property of for example first subject being teached that day that given hour.
Maybe some shorthand to do it in one step? or i have to make temp collection for each time and set iterable to find that?

Comment: What do you mean, "make temp collection"?  You're not making a copy, you're just storing a reference in a variable; that's cheap.  You could just write `subjects.iterator().next()`, if you wanted.

Comment: Ah, didnt know it just makes a reference. Thank you very much for all your help, you saved me lots of frustration!