# Multimap inside Multimap

Tags: java

I have created Integer and Multimap inside Multimap. but I'm not sure how I can put values into Multimap.

this is my code

```
  Multimap<Integer, Multimap<Integer, Integer>> linkedHashMap2 = 
             LinkedListMultimap.create();

  //I'm trying to add values but it throws error
  linkedHashMap2.put(0, (12,15));
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You're probably looking for [putAll](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#putAll(K,%20java.lang.Iterable)), but do beware that the root-level values of your Multimap are going to be Multimaps, not Integers. The *second*-level values are going to be Integers.

Comment: You can refer to the answer section of the below link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27761603/multimap-of-multimap-java-categorize-timetable

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the inner `Multimap` first:

```
Multimap<Integer, Multimap<Integer, Integer>> linkedHashMap2 = LinkedListMultimap.create();
Multimap<Integer, Integer> multiMap = LinkedListMultimap.create();
multiMap.put(12,15);
linkedHashMap2.put(0, multiMap);
```